# Every right $R$-module is finitely cogenerated module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring such that every right $R$-module is simple or decomposable module.

Is it true that every right $R$-module is finitely cogenerated module?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

There are no (ordinary) rings whose modules are all finitely cogenerated. Every nontrivial ring with identity has a simple module, and an infinite direct sum of copies of that module is not finitely cogenerated.

If you restrict to say finitely generated modules are finitely cogenerated, then that would imply the ring is right Artinian. I'm led to believe you know of a non right Artinian ring with the module properties you speak of.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. @rschwieb I am thinking about the ring with this property (i.e. every right $R$-module is simple or decompasable), and I think that $R$ can be right semiartinian ring (i.e. every right $R$-module contains a simple submodule). What do you think of that?

Comment: @Mf.math Earlier it sounded like you knew of such an example, and I am guessing it is not right Artinian, but I don't know. If the paper you read has it, I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: I don't have a paper explains a ring with this property, but I try to discuss such a ring.

Comment: @Mf.math YOu may as well just formulate a question and post it.